# Adding specific gradient to text with CSS

Tags: html, css, text

i have an image with text involved but uploading it and displaying it doesnt help on google search to really find it so i was wondering if i can get specific gradient style on my text.

this is how the text should look.

Can somebody help me on achieving this?

i found this but i dont really know how to adjust it.

```css
.h1 {
      font-size: 72px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;}
```

```html
    <span class="h1">Ανανέωσε ONLINE & πάρε ΔΩΡΟ MB</span>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the non vendor style `background: linear-gradient(to right,#eee, #333);color:transparent;background-clip:text`

Comment: And put a dot before h1 in your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should google for [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) or find in it [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

```css
.h1 {
      margin: auto;
      font-size: 52px;
      font-weight: bold;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #438f3a , #19acdf);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;}
.h1h {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="h1h" ><div class="h1">Ανανέωσε ONLINE & πάρε <br/>ΔΩΡΟ MB!</span></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Can i get the bottom line of text to have bigger font size?

Comment: found it. Thanks again though.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.black-background {
  background: #408e38;
}
.top-clip {
  background: #0d0d0d;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 20%);
    clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 20%);
  padding: 20px;
}

.h1 {
      font-size: 72px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #4cab49 , #1eacce);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="black-background">
  <div class="top-clip">
    <span class="h1">Ανανέωσε ONLINE & πάρε ΔΩΡΟ MB</span>
  </div>
</div>
```